# Mobile.changepage in jQuery not working(white screen)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, eclipse, cordova

i'm using html css and js for building my phonegap project on eclipse and i included my jquery and jquery mobile libraries to use **mobile.changepage** function in my js file but it keeps giving me white screen then returns to the same page (no change occurs)

here are my files:

```js
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
}, false);


document.getElementById("Golds").addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
 alert("omar");
 $.mobile.changePage('login.html');
});


document.getElementById("Titans").addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
 $.mobile.changePage("login.html");
});
//End Login Form//
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Phone Gap trial</title>
<link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.css' />
<link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/font-awesome.min.css' />
 <link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/style.css' />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="ourteam text-center">
 <!--start container-->
 <div  class="team">
 <section class="header">
  <div>
  <h1>Train & Game</h1>
  </div>
  </section>
  <div class="container">
  
   <div class="row">

   <div class="col-xs-4">
   <div class="person">
   <img id="Golds" class="teamphotos img-circle" src="img\golds-gym-logo.png"/>
   <h6>Gold's Gym</h6>
   </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-xs-4">
   <div class="person">
   <img id="Titans" class="teamphotos img-circle" src="img\Titans.jpg"/>
   <h6>Titans Gym</h6>
   </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-xs-4">
   <div class="person">
   <img id="Smart" class="teamphotos img-circle" src="img\smart.png"/>
   <h6>Smart Gym</h6>
   </div>
   </div>

   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row">
   
   <div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class="person">
   <img id="SamiaAllouba" class="teamphotos img-circle" src="img\Samia-Allouba.jpg"/>
   <h6>Samia Allouba</h6>
   </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class="person">
   <img class="teamphotos img-circle" src="img\fibers.jpg"/>
   <h6>Fibers Gym</h6>
   </div>
   </div>
   
   </div>

   </div>
   <!--end container-->
 </div> 
 <!--end team-->
 </div>
<!--Our team div end-->


<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where sits your js code? which file?

Comment: If that's index.js, please move the script tag below the jquery mobile script tag.

Comment: i''m sorry can't understand what do you want me to do ??

Comment: Refer to the answer below

Comment: Ideally speaking. Your code should still work as the event listeners are added via plain vanilla javascript and attached to document. Not sure if the script sequence is definitely an issue (as answered below)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Phone Gap trial</title>
<link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.css' />
<link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/font-awesome.min.css' />
 <link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/style.css' />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ourteam text-center">
    <!--start container-->
    <div  class="team">
    <section class="header">
        <div>
        <h1>Train & Game</h1>
        </div>
        </section>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="person">
            <img id="Golds" class="teamphotos img-circle" src="img\golds-gym-logo.png"/>
            <h6>Gold's Gym</h6>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="person">
            <img id="Titans" class="teamphotos img-circle" src="img\Titans.jpg"/>
            <h6>Titans Gym</h6>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="person">
            <img id="Smart" class="teamphotos img-circle" src="img\smart.png"/>
            <h6>Smart Gym</h6>
            </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="person">
            <img id="SamiaAllouba" class="teamphotos img-circle" src="img\Samia-Allouba.jpg"/>
            <h6>Samia Allouba</h6>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="person">
            <img class="teamphotos img-circle" src="img\fibers.jpg"/>
            <h6>Fibers Gym</h6>
            </div>
            </div>

            </div>

            </div>
            <!--end container-->
    </div> 
    <!--end team-->
    </div>
<!--Our team div end-->


<!--<script src="js/index.js"></script>--> <!-- Commented this Line in your code -->
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script> <!-- Added this line -->
</body>
</html>
```

And Javascript could also be

```
$(document).on('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);


$("#Golds").on('touchstart', function(){
    alert("omar");
    $.mobile.changePage('login.html');
});


$("#Titans").on('touchstart', function(){
    $.mobile.changePage("login.html");
});
```